# laravel - Pass query result from HomeController to home blade view

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to pass a query result from HomeController to home blade view using the below code but it doesn't seem to work that way.

```
public function index()
{
  $result=DB::table('tablename')->where('this', 'that')->where('this', 'that')->value('value');      
  return view('home',compact ('result'));        
}
```

if I write just `return $result` I am able to print the values which means I am getting the data.

in my home view I have something like this

```
@if(!$result->isEmpty())     
 // print $result
@else
 //do something else if $result is empty
@endif
```

my route is this `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');`

I also tried this `return view('home'$result));` based on a tutorial I have seen which seemed to work fine but in my case it does not work!

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code is correct... where are you showing the result though? you can't print the `$result` in the `@else` block because it's never reached

Comment: @c I need to print them in the @else block! any ideas on how to make it reach there?

Comment: Yes, remove the `!` in the `@if` block, this is basic boolean logic

Comment: ahh sorry made a mistake with the comments it should be the other way around... if i remove the `!` then i get an error of: `Call to a member function isEmpty() on string`

Comment: Okay I answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're returning a string value and not a collection, you should use the `empty()` function for the check

```
@if(!empty($result))     
 // print $result
@else
 //do something else if $result is empty
@endif
```

[empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) in PHP docs